# Apple notifications not delivered using development certificates in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios8, apple-push-notifications, xcode6

I have implement the push notifications in my project and i have strictly followed all the steps of Ray Wenderlich  Push Notifications,earlier i have implemented notification using development certificates successfully.

But this time when i checked the notifications using terminal with SimplePushp.php file,the terminal displays that message have been successfully delivered but my device doesn't receive any notifications.

I have used development certificate and i am checking the notification on my iPhone 5s device.
I have repeated the steps several times but did't get the notification on my device.
Please help.

Comment: In Xcode 6 you cannot use development certificate for Push notifications.Use Ad-Hoc instead.

Comment: can we test on Ad-Hoc using terminal as we used to test while using Development Certificates earlier.

Comment: Yes, but you have to generate new private key for Ad-hoc certificate and use production APNS instead.For more provider information see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1

Comment: @Foriger thanks for your reply.can you please tell me how can i find the device token from Ad-Hoc using console.

Comment: Device token is generated when device register for remote notifications.To take token you must implement method :-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken which gives you device token.After that you can provide token to your server.I don't know how this is done in RW tutorial.